# Reload select when choose select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I have 2 field select. 
I want when a value is choose in the first one, the second select will reload and show some values that correspond to the first select.
Example : 
States and city :

```
<select id="billing_state" data-placeholder="State / County">
    <option value="">Select an option…</option>
    <option value="CA" selected="selected">California</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
</select>
```

When you choose California reload field select city.

```
    <select id="billing_city" data-placeholder="City">
        <option value="">Select an option…</option>
        <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="SD">San Diego</option>
        ...
    </select>
```

And when you choose Texas reload field select city.

```
    <select id="billing_city" data-placeholder="City">
        <option value="">Select an option…</option>
        <option value="">Dallas</option>
        <option value="HT">Houston</option>
        ...
    </select>
```

I have tried to find some way. But not very effective. Maybe I have no knowledge about it. Can you help and give me an example on jsfiddle?

Thanks very much!
P/s: Oh .I came across it. It is currently visible and hidden when selected. I watched a similar post but was not feasible for my problem. I use wordpress. And the data fields are already available, I just want to reload it to show it. I choose new states but it does not reload the city. I refreshed the web page and it reloaded and displayed a new city field.

Comment: Hi, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can use [SO Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#billing_state').change(function() {
  var countrycode = $(this).val();

  if (countrycode != "") {
    $('#billing_city option').hide();
    $('#billing_city option:eq(0)').show();
    $('#billing_city option[data-parent=' + countrycode + ']').show();
    $('#billing_city').val("")
  }
});
```

Note: I've added `data-parent="CA"` you the "City" `options`. Like:

```
<option data-parent="CA" value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
<option data-parent="CA" value="SD">San Diego</option>
<option data-parent="TX" value="DA">Dallas</option>
<option data-parent="TX" value="HT">Houston</option>
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#billing_state').change(function() {
  var countrycode = $(this).val();

  if (countrycode != "") {
    $('#billing_city option').hide();
    $('#billing_city option:eq(0)').show();
    $('#billing_city option[data-parent=' + countrycode + ']').show();
    $('#billing_city').val("")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="billing_state" data-placeholder="State / County">
  <option value="">Select an option…</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
</select>

<select id="billing_city" data-placeholder="City">
  <option value="">Select an option…</option>
  <option data-parent="CA" value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
  <option data-parent="CA" value="SD">San Diego</option>
  <option data-parent="TX" value="DA">Dallas</option>
  <option data-parent="TX" value="HT">Houston</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh .I came across it. It is currently visible and hidden when selected. I watched a similar post but was not feasible for my problem. I use wordpress. And the data fields are already available, I just want to reload it to show it. I choose new states but it does not reload the city. I refreshed the web page and it reloaded and displayed a new city field.

Answer (score 0):

Please find link below:
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/8Lk5w0xn/11/

```
<select id="billing_state" data-placeholder="State / County">
    <option value="">Select an option…</option>
    <option value="CA" selected="selected">California</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
</select>

<div>
  <select id="second_dropdown" data-placeholder="Please Select">
    <option value="">Select an option…</option>
    <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="SD">San Diego</option>
  </select>
</div>


$("#billing_state").on("change", function(e) {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
    if (currentVal === "CA") {
    var optn = '<option value="">Select an option…</option><option value="LA">Los Angeles</option><option value="SD">San Diego</option>';
  } else if (currentVal === "TX") {
    var optn = '<option value="">Select an option…</option><option value="">Dallas</option><option value="HT">Houston</option>';
  } else {
    var optn = '<option value="">Select an option…</option>'
  }
  $("#second_dropdown option").remove();
  $("#second_dropdown").append(optn);
})
```